# Launch pyqt dialog window multiple times

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4

I've put together some test code to figure out how to launch a simple pyqt Ui_Dialog multiple times during a script.  I want launch the window depending on certain conditions as my script is running.  The idea is that it is just a popup notification window with different text and the user will click ok.  I designed the window in QtDesigner and inherited the generated code in another class:

```
class MsgWindow(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self,parent)
        self.app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
       self.ui.setupUi(self)

       QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.OK, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'),self.close)

    def AddText(self,text):
        """ Method to add text to textEdit box """
        self.ui.textEdit.append(text + '\n') 

    def closeEvent(self, event): 
        print "Closing the app" 
        #self.deleteLater()  

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MsgWindow()

    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

So then my test script just launches the window (user closes it) and repeats.  The issue is that after the last close, python crashes (python.exe has stopped working).  Here is the test script code:

```
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
dlg = MsgWindow()
for x in range(0,3):    
    dlg.AddText("This is a test, iteration: %d"%x)
    dlg.exec_()

    #sys.exit(app.exec_())
    time.sleep(2)
```

What is the correct way to do this without crashing?

Thank you.

Comment: You need a `Main Widget` that keeps running in the background when the `Message Window` is being called, closed, called, closed. If you only launch the Message Window, python will be terminated when that window is closed. For each GUI in my program, I always have two classes: one for the construction and one for the code. You can safely call `self.app.close()` on the Message Window, as long as the `QMainWindow` is still running.

Comment: So the QMainWindow is constructed but doesn't need to be shown?

Comment: @ND24 I have tested your code, and I only made one modification that is to remove the following instruction `self.app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)`, and it works for me correctly.

Comment: thank you @eyllanesc...it works now for me as well.